# Use formatting tags in XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags, formatting

Below is the source code for XML and XSLT file, the output that I am getting is "Bold Text Italics Text" the bold and italics formatting tags are ignored. How can I adjust this code to make sure ALL tags are applied and my output text is in bold/italic?

XML File (text.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<examples>
    <example><b>Bold Text</b> <i>Italics Text</i></example>
</examples>
```

XSL File (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="examples/example"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use `xsl:copy-of` as the input format is the one expected for `example`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:copy-of select="examples/example"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem is that it would apply those tags to the entire line, I need to bold half and the second half need to be in italics.

Comment: @Alex since your input XML has the `<b>` and `<i>` tags in place, i think changing `xsl:value-of` to `xsl:copy-of` will work for you. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe it is so simple to do. I have been searching for hours.